# How to parse a custom string using optparse?

Tags: python, optparse

**How to parse a custom string using optparse, instead of command line argument?**

I want to parse a string that I get from using `raw_input()`.
How can I use optparse for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`optparse` expects a list of values that have been broken up shell-style (which is what `argv[1:]` is). To accomplish the same starting with a string, try this:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
# Set up your OptionParser

inp = raw_input("Enter some crap: ")

try: (options, args) = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(inp))
except:
    # Error handling.
```

The optional argument to `parse_args` is where you substitute in your converted string.

Be advised that `shlex.split` can exception, as can `parse_args`. When you're dealing with input from the user, it's wise to expect both cases.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [shlex module](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) to split the input first.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split(raw_input())
this is "a test" of shlex
['this', 'is', 'a test', 'of', 'shlex']
```

Comment: i need to parse the input.. how can i do that after making it into a list?